# How can I calculate 2 column with time data and save it to the "total column"?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I'm making an attendance system. I want to calculate the total hours from time in to time out and display it to the total hours column.

I tried this code but this does not work. I'm doing this on my User Model

```
public function total()
{
    $now = $this->freshTimestamp();

    return $this->employeeAttendance()
                ->where('date', Carbon::now('Asia/Manila')->toDateString())
                ->whereNull('total')
                ->firstOrFail()
                ->update([
                    'total' => DB::table('attendance')->where('id')->sum(DB::raw('timeIn - timeOut')),
                ]);
}
```

This my Time In model

```
public function timeIn()
{
    $now = $this->freshTimestamp();

    return $this->employeeAttendance()->create([
        'name' => auth()->user()->name,
        'date' => Carbon::now('Asia/Manila')->toDateString(),
        'timeIn' => Carbon::now('Asia/Manila')->format('H:i:s'),
    ]);
}
```

This my Time Out in model

```
public function timeOut()
{
    $now = $this->freshTimestamp();

    return $this->employeeAttendance()
                ->where('date', Carbon::now('Asia/Manila')->toDateString())
                ->whereNull('timeOut')
                ->firstOrFail()
                ->update([
                    'timeOut' => Carbon::now('Asia/Manila')->format('H:i:s'),
                ]);
}
```

This my Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->user()->timeIn();

    return back();
}

public function update(Request $request)
{
    $request->user()->timeOut();

    return back();
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: If you can calculate it in a query, then dont store in the database. There are to many ways that it can be wrong due to a change in the data used to calculate not being propergated into the total

Comment: do you update "timeOut" again in total method?

Comment: @Mehran Sorry typo didn't notice but it still not working.

Comment: @Gordon It's not calculating the "timeIn" and "timeOut" its not displaying anything on "total".